# Is it possible to split a string by <b> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, split

For instance I have a string:

```
str = "Hello bob my name is john"
```

which in html is represented as 3 entities being:

```
<b>Hello bob</b><b>my name</b><b>is john</b>
```

Is there a way I can split this so that I get:

```
["Hello bob", "my name", "is john"]
```

I know the initial format is not very good, but I am drawing some text out of wikipedia via the wikimedia api, and from that I want to be able to be able to potentially plot each 'entity' on a map.
 I have tried spliting with `(" ")` but obviously that is not much good to me if the entity consists of 2 or more words!

Comment: How does `str` equal the text with the bold tags?

Comment: You'd likely need some more sophisticated method of extracting useful info, like regex or a parser. However, if this case is all you need, have you tried splitting by `</b>`? Meaning, can you access the html tags themselves, then split by them and strip them out?

Comment: Are you splitting str or the html with <b> tags?

Comment: Go to developer tools, copy the HTML chunk. Split using `</b>` and then delete the `<b>`

Comment: if the `str` doesn't include the html tags, then you can't do this. You need to get the `html()` property instead of the `text()` property

Comment: All good guys, worked it out...not thinking. need to split by `</b>` and then delete the `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
var s = "<b>Hello bob</b><b>my name</b><b>is john</b>";
var arr = s.match(/<b>.*?<\/b>/g);
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/, "$1");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question then you could do it with something like,

```js
var v = document.getElementById("test");
var str = v.innerHTML;
var arr = str.replace("<b>","").split("</b>");
var out = document.getElementById("out");
out.innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <b>Hello bob</b> <b>my name</b> <b>is john</b>
</div>
<div id="out">
</div>
```